# JavaScript - Calling a function again is not working

Tags: javascript

This is kind of hard to explain, but I want to make it so when someone gets the answer right to a question, they get a new question. I have tried calling the function more than once but that doesn't work. I have tried many things like making cookies, but I can't get it to work. Here is my current code:

```js
//Getting elements
var ques = document.getElementById("question");
var ansBox = document.getElementById("ansBox");
var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
var isCorrect = document.getElementById("isCorrect");
var quesNum = document.getElementById("quesNum");

//Variables
var num1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
var num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
var ans = num1 + num2;
var questionNumber = 1;

quesNum.innerHTML = questionNumber;

//Check if answer is correct or not
function checkAns() {
  if(ansBox.value == ans) {
    isCorrect.innerHTML = "Good job! Your answer was correct!";
    questionNumber++;
    quesNum.innerHTML = questionNumber;
    ques.innerHTML = " ";
    question();
    //Call if statement when questionNumber = 10 and disable submitBtn and ansBox
    if(questionNumber == 10) {
      isCorrect.innerHTML = "Congratulations! You have completed all 10 questions! Refresh the page to do more!";
      ansBox.disabled = true;
      submitBtn.disabled = true;
    }
  } else {
    isCorrect.innerHTML = "Uh-oh, your answer was incorrect!";
  }
}

//Ask question
function question() {
  ques.innerHTML = num1 + " + " + num2;
}

//Call question function
question();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

div {
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <h1>Edu Game One</h1>
    <h3 id="question"></h3>
    <input type="text" id="ansBox" />
    <button id="submitBtn" type="submit" onclick="checkAns()">Submit</button>
    <p id="isCorrect"></p>
    <span id="quesNum"></span>
    <span>/ 10</span>
  </div>

  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"Can I reload a function?"* What do you mean by "reload"? You can certainly *call* a function  multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that generates the two random numbers is currently not inside a function, so it runs once when the page first loads. You just need to move those lines *inside* your `question()` function, so then each time `question()` is called you'll get new random values.

You'll want to set the `ans` value from there too (but leave `ans` as a global variable so that it can be checked from your other function):

```
function question() {
  var num1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  var num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  ans = num1 + num2;

  ques.innerHTML = num1 + " + " + num2;
}
```

In context:

```js
//Getting elements
var ques = document.getElementById("question");
var ansBox = document.getElementById("ansBox");
var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
var isCorrect = document.getElementById("isCorrect");
var quesNum = document.getElementById("quesNum");

//Variables
var ans;
var questionNumber = 1;

quesNum.innerHTML = questionNumber;

//Check if answer is correct or not
function checkAns() {
  if(ansBox.value == ans) {
    isCorrect.innerHTML = "Good job! Your answer was correct!";
    questionNumber++;
    quesNum.innerHTML = questionNumber;
    ques.innerHTML = " ";
    question();
    //Call if statement when questionNumber = 10 and disable submitBtn and ansBox
    if(questionNumber == 10) {
      isCorrect.innerHTML = "Congratulations! You have completed all 10 questions! Refresh the page to do more!";
      ansBox.disabled = true;
      submitBtn.disabled = true;
    }
  } else {
    isCorrect.innerHTML = "Uh-oh, your answer was incorrect!";
  }
}

//Ask question
function question() {
  var num1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  var num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  ans = num1 + num2;

  ques.innerHTML = num1 + " + " + num2;
}

//Call question function
question();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

div {
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <h1>Edu Game One</h1>
    <h3 id="question"></h3>
    <input type="text" id="ansBox" />
    <button id="submitBtn" type="submit" onclick="checkAns()">Submit</button>
    <p id="isCorrect"></p>
    <span id="quesNum"></span>
    <span>/ 10</span>
  </div>

  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, you may want to move the following lines:

```
questionNumber++;
quesNum.innerHTML = questionNumber;
```

...to be before the `if` statement, because at the moment it doesn't count questions attempted, it counts only questions that were answered correctly.

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much! I am trying to learn JavaScript, so can you please explain why that was the problem?

Comment: @Jordan: `var num1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);` was only executed *once* on page load.